# Is there a term for words that are sounded out initialisms?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, initialisms

The words "okay" and "emcee" seem to both be somewhat widely accepted (at least, I can find both in several dictionaries). But it seems to be agreed that these are simply sounded-out spellings of the initialisms "O.K." and "M.C." respectively.

Are there any other words like this, and is there a general term for them?

Comment: I could not find any word for them, but I would like to propose the portmanteau "acronomatopoeia"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an official term for words made by spelling out the name sounds of an initialism's letters. Twelve years ago today, on 2000-01-06, [Lee Daniel Quinn suggested calling this type of word a *vocologue*](http://archiver.rootsweb.ancestry.com/th/read/WORDS/2000-01/0947041811), but his attempted neologism doesn't seem to have caught on.

I'd like to see a happier fate for wim 9's *acronomatopoeia*, suggested in the comments above. I like the cleverness of the portmanteau formation, and it can be reasonably-well understood to mean *a word formed by the sounds of an initialism's letter names.*

I was able to find only the following 9 common examples of *acronomatopoeia*:

- *Teevee* = TV (Television)
- *Emcee*= MC (Master of ceremonies)
- *Deejay*= DJ (Disk Jockey)
- *Veejay*= VJ (video jockey)
- *Jaycee*= JC (Junior Chamber of Commerce.)
- *Jayvee*= JV (Junior Varsity)
- *Okay* = OK ([Oll Korrect or Old Kinderhok](http://www.straightdope.com/classics/a2_250.html))
- *Kayo*= KO (Knock Out)
- *Arby's* = RB's ([Raffel Brothers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arby%27s#History))

Comment: Queuecee QC (Queen's council = a type of lawyer)

Comment: @MartinBeckett  Interesting. I'd never seen or heard that one. Must be BritE, no? So, _Queue_=Q and _cee_=C? Wouldn't just Que do for Q? I goggled it, but couldn't find anything. I'm wondering how you pronounce it. Which syllable is stressed? [CUE see] or [cue SEE] or otherwise?

Comment: @mgb: tongue-in-cheek I imagine, but it would at least assist the apocryphal barrister who proudly signed himself *John Smith QC* and got a reply addressed to Mr J S Qc.

Answer (score 0):

The only specific wording I have seen for these words are : **Plural colloquials**

Plural covers the transition from letters to spoken words, and Colloquial covering words appearing out of common use.

Other similarities:

- DJ deejay
- MC emcee
- In American English, jaycee is used for "Junior Chamber of Commerce member".