# What kind of abbreviations are "Bee Gees", "Eminem", etc?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, abbreviations

The ["Bee Gees"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee_Gees) is actually a stylised expansion of the initials BGs, which in turn refers to initials of Barry Gibb, DJ Bill Gates and Bill Goode (or simply means Brothers Gibb).

["Eminem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminem) comes from M&M, initials of Marshall Mathers.

Similarly, ["Emcee"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emcee) from pronunciation of M.C., abbreviation of master of ceremonies, a noun phrase attested from the 1660s.

In my place I see a lot of companies titled similarly, PeeKays (from initials PK), CeePee electronics, Kay Pee Em tours and travels etc.

Now, my username NVZ is an *initialism*. What if I expand it into En Vee Zee?

**What is this type of naming called?**

I don't think it's simply an acronym, or an initialism.

Comment: Stylisation, perhaps?

Comment: I thought that "Bee Gees" stood for "[Brothers Gibb](http://www.brothersgibb.org/)."

Comment: Eminem= M&M (Marshall Mathers)

Comment: Closely related: [Is IOU an abbreviation, an acronym, or an initialism?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/204086/is-iou-an-abbreviation-an-acronym-or-an-initialism)

Comment: It definitely stands for "Brothers Gibb"  (note: "Gibb" not "Gibbs").  "DJ Bill Gates" is pretty laughable, where did you get that from?

Comment: @NVZ - on reading that, and this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bee_Gees#History i totally stand corrected.   I guess i found it funny because I pictured the Microsoft founder with one headphone, geeing up a crowd for a bass drop.

Comment: I don't know, but I'm more upset that I DID know the Brothers Gibb thing. Shouldn't there by a word for "things we should just all forget"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Is there a term for words that are sounded out initialisms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53567/is-there-a-term-for-words-that-are-sounded-out-initialisms)* Also see *[Why does the word “emcee” exist?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/60423)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say it aloud, then it's just an initialism.  If you proceed to spell it out with complete syllables, rather than letters, i thought at first you could say it's a "phonetically spelled initialism".   On the other hand, "phonetically spelled" may suggest that a phonetic alphabet should be used, ie one in which the symbols represent specific sounds, unlike the more flexible regular alphabet.

So, perhaps the best reference is **sensational spelling**, in which a word is deliberately misspelled for effect.  This is commonly used in branding to give an impression of uniqueness, and, perhaps more importantly, to allow the trademarking of the term.  ("Blu-ray", "Mortal Kombat" etc - see ["Sensational spelling" on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensational_spelling))

So, i think you could call it a **sensationally spelled initialism**.